# Drawing R in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to learn css each day I pick a letter and draw it in CSS. I am struck by the letter "R".
I created two inner div one for semicircle and another for dialog. Unable to draw diagonal.

```css
.box{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width:200px;
  height:300px;
  background-color: purple;
}

.inner-top{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width: 180px;
  height:150px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border : 5px solid blue;
  border-radius :  0px 150px 150px 0px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="inner-top"></div>
  <div class="inner-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this help? https://codepen.io/rhgksrua/pen/GgbLKM

Comment: Honestly?  Completely wrong approach. A smart coder would simply use a `SVG` or `clip-path` instead of creating so many elements and/or using pseudo-elements.

Comment: I guess this is just a learning exercise rather than serious production code? Have you investigated before and after pseudo elements? You could draw the diagonal with one of those attached to the inner-bottom perhaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try making normal lines and using skew.

```css
.box{
  position: absolute;
  width:200px;
  height:300px;
  background-color: purple;
}

.inner-top{
  position: absolute;
  width: 180px;
  height:150px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border : 5px solid blue;
  border-radius :  0px 150px 150px 0px;  
}
.left-line {
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  background: blue;
  width: 5px;
  }
  
 .diagonal-line {
 position: absolute;
 height: 300px;
 width: 5px;
 background: blue;
 transform: skewX(30deg); /* edit this and */
 margin: 0px 90px;        /* this by your preference */
 }
 
 /* also I forgot about white space between left line and diagonal and im lazy to do it now */
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="diagonal-line"></div>
  <div class="left-line"></div>
  <div class="inner-top"></div>
  <div class="inner-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Btw, if you enjoy doing random stuff in CSS, I recommend you trying out CSSbattle:
https://cssbattle.dev